# Image cropper makes my page slow

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

On my page there are a log of images (appr. 100-120), and I'm using the Image cropper.

```
<img width="303" src="@Umbraco.TypedMedia((int)categoryImage.Id).GetCropUrl(303, 404)&quality=75" alt="" />
```

According to google pagespeed and gmetrix the biggest problem is: "Remove query strings from static resources".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between Umbraco 6 and 7 in the image cropper function. In Umbraco 6 it is generated in the media folder and the url is without querystring. (a named crop)

In Umbraco 7 the generated image is cached in the \App_Data\cache so only the first hit should be slower. But the url is with a querystring.

A false positive, in terms of speed, it does not matter much.

You can probably come up with somethings like, url rewrite or something but then you lose flexibility, or another cropper, like the Umbraco 6 way, with minimum speed profit. or CSS sprites.